# Did Discord change something?

Tags: discord.py

On 10/26,

- my react to role (gains access to my server, used over 2000 times) has stopped working.
- I had a "watching #### users" status for the bot, that has stopped working, it went from 20k users now it says 6 users.
- 4 of my bots which have been online for half a year and post to discord many times a day has stopped working. (The bot still runs, it just doesnt post to discord...)

The server the code is running on has multiple other bots that are running just fine. I just find it odd that these all went down at the same time.

Anyone know if anything has changed?

Answer (score 1):

yes there has been a new update, like u need intents or something

so data on members and stuff are hidden u have to enable intents to get this data

in discord.com/developer like if u go in the bot mode

update rolled out on 27 that is when i encountered it

Comment: Sadly that did not fix my issue, on the read me it says it will be mandatory from Oct 7th but my bots only stopped Oct 26th.